# Python GET request with a nested parameters

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to write API client for Jira with Python *requests* lib according reference:
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/

Request to be generated:

http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=charlie&startAt=2&maxResults=2

As I know, parameters to GET request should be passed as dictionary like:

```
 params = {'assignee':'charlie', 'startAt':'2'}
```

But all main parameters are nested in **jql** parameter, so I assume there is should be a nested dict like:

```
 params = {'jql': {'assignee': 'charlie'}}
```

But that's doesn't work - as a result I've got request to

```
/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee
```

As expect `/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=charlie`
using

```
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

How to manage such request?

*UPD:*

To be more clear, I'd like to wrap request in a method with kwargs, like:

```
search_query(assignee='charlie', startAt=1, etc...)
```

And then generate a query using this params, but maybe there are any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing couple of key parameters, mainly if you are pushing data via requests, the data go into the `data` argument. Also the moment you push JSON data, you need to set the headers correctly as well. The last thing is authentication. Have you tried to post it in this manner?

```
import json
requests.post(url=url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
              auth=('username', 'password'), # your username and password
              data=json.dumps(params)
              )
```

Also by the JIRA documentation you've provided (https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/) if you want to push query as data, the url you want is `/rest/api/2/search`.

Comment: The question is about Get request - it doesn't use data to push, just a parameters in a url string like ?param1=value1&param2=value2